# Backbone error can not call method 'toJSON'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I wanna render every waiter from my collection but console still show me error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined

this is my code :

```
 (function() {

    window.App = {

        Models: {},
        Views: {},
        Collections: {}

    };

    window.template = function(id) {

        return _.template( $('id' + id).html() );

    },
```

// WAITER MODEL

```
    App.Models.Waiter = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: function() {
            return {
                title: 'Waiter Name',
                id: []
            };
        }
    });
```

// A LIST OF WAITERS COLLECTION

```
   App.Collections.Waiters = Backbone.Collection.extend({

       model: App.Models.Waiter
   });
```

// VIEW FOR ALL WAITERS

```
   App.Views.Waiters = Backbone.View.extend({

       tagName: 'ul',

       render: function() {

           this.collection.each(function(waiter) {

               var waiterView = new App.Views.Waiter({ model: waiter });

               this.$el.append(waiterView.render().el);

           }, this);

           return this;
       }
   });
```

// A VIEW FOR ONE PERSON

```
    App.Views.Waiter = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'li',

        template: _.template("<%= title %><%= id %>"),

        render: function() {

            this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );

            return this;

        },
    });


       waitersCollection = new App.Collections.Waiters([
           {
               title: 'ferko fristansky',
               id: 2
           },
           {
               title: 'ferko bandaska',
               id: 3
           },
           {
               title: 'fvwerv fristansky',
               id: 4
           }    

       ]);

       var waitersView = new App.Views.Waiter({ collection: waitersCollection });

        $(document.body).append(waitersView.render().el);


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your `waiterView` with a collection:

```
var waiterView = new App.Views.Waiter({ collection: waitersCollection });
```

but `App.Views.Waiter` is a model-based view; that means that `this.model` will be `undefined` inside your `App.Views.Waiter` and so this will fail:

```
this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
// this is undefined -------------^^^^^
```

You probably want to create an `App.Views.Waiters` instead:

```
var waitersView = new App.Views.Waiters({ collection: waitersCollection });
```

Then, inside `App.Views.Waiters`, you'd create one `App.Views.Waiter` for each model in the collection rather than a `new App.Views.extend({ model: waiter })`:

```
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(waiter) {
        var waiterView = new App.Views.Waiter({ model: waiter });
        this.$el.append(waiterView.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

---

As an aside, be careful with this:

```
App.Models.Waiter = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: 'Waiter Name',
        id: []
    }
});
```

The values from [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) are shallow copied so everything that uses those defaults will end up using exactly the same `id` array and that can lead to strange bugs when you have several models sharing the same `id` array. If you have mutable values in `defaults`, you usually want to use a function instead so that everyone gets their own distinct values:

```
App.Models.Waiter = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            title: 'Waiter Name',
            id: []
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a typo, you're still saying `var waitersView = new App.Views.Waiter` when you should be saying `var waitersView = new App.Views.Waiters`. It works if you fix that: http://jsfiddle.net/6D2Xu/